# from one list to a second List

Tags: swiftui

From a the first List view the user selects a row. Then the second List view comes up, the user selects a row again and then we go the detail view (see screendumps). There are a couple of things I don't understand.

1. Why is the 'pantanal' image repeated on all three views?
2. On the detail view I get two 'back buttons'. I just want one of
   course. And btw why is one button called 'Back' instead of
   'Development'?
3. Why is there so much room in List view 2 between the image and the
   list?

My code for the first List view:

```
struct EggList: View {
    var eggs = Egg.all()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Image("Pantanal")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .clipped()
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 250)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

            NavigationView {
                List(eggs) { egg in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EggDayList(egg: egg)) {
                        CellRow(egg: egg)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Egg overview"), displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code for the second List view:

```
struct EggDayList: View {
    var egg = Egg.all().first
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(egg!.calcWeights) { eggDay in
                NavigationLink(destination: EggDetail()) {
                    CellDayRow(eggDay: eggDay)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Development")
    }
}
```

[image: The first List view]
[image: The second List view]
[image: The detail view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 : You defined multiple navigations. But first one repeats on every page. So you will see the header on every page. If you don't like this behavior, move the image **inside** the `NavigationView`

2.1 : Because you set two navigations, get rid of the second one and you will see only one back button

2.2 : Because `navigationBarTitle` should be **inside** `NavigationView`. like:

```
NavigationView {
   Text("test").navigationBarTitle("This navigation title will be used for next back button")
}
```

3 : Because of multiple `NavigationView`s, each time you go to next page, new `NavigationView` initialized above the list (without title) looks like empty space.

**Note that** `NavigationView` is like `UINavigationController`. So each time you build one, it's like you build a new controller. But only one controller is needed.